# MsGraph get users filter to get only person account

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to list users and filter only real person account using MsGraph users API ?`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

Currently, it returns person but also conference rooms and others.

I see that you can retrieve persons you work with using people API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/people?$filter=personType/class eq 'Person' and personType/subclass eq 'OrganizationUser'
```

Is there anything similar for users ?

Thanks you !

Comment: Could you pls give us a screenshot about your api response?  per my understanding, `/users` should only return users, so I don't know if a Conference room will contain the same properties. By the way, if real users are always had user Principal Name like `xx@aa.onmicrosoft.com` then you may use filter query option to filter the `userPrincipalName` value.

Comment: [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-all-users-with-a-mail-that-ends-with-acontosocom-including-a-count-of-returned-objects-with-the-results-ordered-by-userprincipalname) is filtering mail property.

Answer (score 0):

The current options are to either use the [People API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) like you said or the [List orgContacts endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/orgcontact-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) from the Microsoft Graph Rest API Beta.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contacts
```

This returns the list of organizational contacts for the organization.

Comment: Yeah, my only problem on using People API was that I have to get users from Users endpoint then loop on each users to get if it's a person or not. Not a big deal for hundred data but for an organization of thousands users, it will be problematic